# Cannot get my while statement to work properly

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, infinite

The error in this program is the while statement in the main method. It was working before in the sense that when I invalid input value it would stop and exit program and when I input proper value it would loop through the while statement once but suddenly after more work too my code it loops infinity for any input below 1025. Ignore the sloppiness of the output of the program as I am still editing that, the main problem is why it does not stop looping in the while statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DNS
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int y;
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);

        System.out.println("java DisplayNumberSystems");
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal value to display to: ");
        y = input.nextInt();

        while(y !=1025)
        {

            for(int x=0; x <=y; x++)
            {
                System.out.println("Decimal");
                System.out.println(x);
            }


            for(int i=0; i <=y; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Binary");
                convertToBinary(i);
            }

            System.out.println("");             

            for(int z=0; z <=y; z++)
            {
                System.out.println("Hex");
                convertToHex(z);
            }

            System.out.println("");

            for(int d=0; d <=y; d++)
            {
                System.out.println("Octal");
                convertToOctal(d);
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }
    }

    public static void convertToBinary(int x)
    {

        if(x >0)
        {

            convertToBinary(x/2);
            System.out.printf(x%2 + "");

        }

    }

    public static void convertToOctal(int x)
    {
        int rem; 

        while(x >0)
        {
            rem = x%8;
            System.out.printf("%d", rem);
            x=x/8;
        }
    }

    public static void convertToHex(int x)
    {
        int rem;

        while(x >0)
        {

        rem = x%16;
            switch(rem)
            {
                case 1: 
                    System.out.printf("1");
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    System.out.printf("2");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.printf("3");
                    break;

                case 4: 
                    System.out.printf("4");
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.printf("5");
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.printf("6");
                    break;

                case 7: 
                    System.out.printf("7");
                    break;

                case 8:
                    System.out.printf("8");
                    break;

                case 9:
                    System.out.printf("9");
                    break;

                case 10: 
                    System.out.printf("A");
                    break;
                case 11: 
                    System.out.printf("B");
                    break;

                case 12: 
                    System.out.printf("C");
                    break;

                case 13: 
                    System.out.printf("D");
                    break;

                case 14: 
                    System.out.printf("E");
                    break;

                case 15: 
                    System.out.printf("F");
                    break;
            }
            x=x/16;
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }

}
```

Comment: Holy cow code repetition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a `while` loop if you are going to execute it only once ? Consider `if` instead.

Never mind, how about breaking the `while` loop ?
You can use `break;` wherever applicable, to stop execution of a loop.

For example :

```
while (y != 1025) {

    for (int x = 0; x <= y; x++) {
        System.out.println("Decimal");
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Binary");
        convertToBinary(i);
    }

    System.out.println("");

    for (int z = 0; z <= y; z++) {
        System.out.println("Hex");
        convertToHex(z);
    }

    System.out.println("");

    for (int d = 0; d <= y; d++) {
        System.out.println("Octal");
        convertToOctal(d);
        System.out.println("");
    }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not increment y's value anywhere inside the while.
So, for a value of y below 1025, say 100.y is always 100 and every time while checks the condition y!= 1025 is true.So, please put a increment `y = y + 1` or anything and it will do.

Comment: i cant increment y because it is what my for functions within it count to. i also changed it to <= instead of != and it still loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(y !=1025)
```

In this line Your loop work while y is `lower than 1025` and `higher than 1025`. 
Also You **didn't** change `y value`.

Comment: i changed it now from != to <=. my y is suppost to stay the same and my for function would stop after reaching y. the problem is that they just restart after reaching the y value.

Answer (score 0):

It will always loop, just as the people above have said. Unless y changes, it will always, always be not equal to 1025 unless it's original value is 1025.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Should you be including  y = input.nextInt(); inside the loop so that the loop will break if the condition becomes true?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a break at the end of the while loop, it effectively makes the while loop redundant. It will loop once then exit. If you only want to run the loop for a value other than 1025, you should use an if then statement...

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your `while` loop is running infinity times is because you're not updating (perhaps increment) the value of `y`. You may want to add something like the following statement inside your loop:

```
y++;
```

That will increment the value of `y` by 1 at every loop iteration